# Flask function to return object to another function

Tags: python, function, flask

New to flask and trying to understand how to pass function arguments between functions. I need to know how I can accomplish this:

```
@home.route('/admin/dashboard')
@login_required
def admin_dashboard():
    if not current_user.is_admin:
        abort(403)

    td = timedelta
    t = date.today()
    ssun = t + td(days=-1 - t.weekday())
    mmon = t + td(days=0 - t.weekday())
    ttue = t + td(days=1 - t.weekday())
    wwed = t + td(days=2 - t.weekday())
    tthu = t + td(days=3 - t.weekday())
    ffri = t + td(days=4 - t.weekday())
    ssat = t + td(days=5 - t.weekday())
    today = t.strftime('%#m-%#d-%Y')
    sun = ssun.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    mon = mmon.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    tue = ttue.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    wed = wwed.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    thu = tthu.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    fri = ffri.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    sat = ssat.strftime('%#m-%#d')

    return render_template('home/admin_dashboard.html', today=today, 
                        sun=sun, mon=mon, tue=tue, wed=wed, thu=thu,
                        fri=fri, sat=sat, title="Dashboard-Admin")
```

Which is working perfectly!
With something more along the lines of this:

```
def get_dates():
    td = timedelta
    t = date.today()
    ssun = t + td(days=-1 - t.weekday())
    mmon = t + td(days=0 - t.weekday())
    ttue = t + td(days=1 - t.weekday())
    wwed = t + td(days=2 - t.weekday())
    tthu = t + td(days=3 - t.weekday())
    ffri = t + td(days=4 - t.weekday())
    ssat = t + td(days=5 - t.weekday())
    today = t.strftime('%#m-%#d-%Y')
    sun = ssun.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    mon = mmon.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    tue = ttue.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    wed = wwed.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    thu = tthu.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    fri = ffri.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    sat = ssat.strftime('%#m-%#d')

    return (today, sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat)

@home.route('/admin/dashboard')
@login_required
def admin_dashboard():
    if not current_user.is_admin:
        abort(403)

    get_dates()

    return render_template('home/admin_dashboard.html', today=today, 
                        sun=sun, mon=mon, tue=tue, wed=wed, thu=thu,
                        fri=fri, sat=sat, title="Dashboard-Admin")
```

Which doesn't even come close to working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your 'admin_dashboard' function:

```
(today, sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat) = get_dates()
```

Comment: @Julien Spronck, while your answer worked perfectly also, I chose this one as I believe it makes the code look cleaner. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the variables `today`, `sun`, `mon`, ... in your `admin_dashboard()` function, you need to define them inside the `admin_dashboard()` function.

```
today, sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat = get_dates()
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of variables defined in `get_dates()` is local to that function.
You cannot *"use"* these variables outside this function unless you explicitly define them again in the next function or globally.

```
from datetime import *

def get_dates():
    td = timedelta
    t = date.today()
    ssun = t + td(days=-1 - t.weekday())
    mmon = t + td(days=0 - t.weekday())
    ttue = t + td(days=1 - t.weekday())
    wwed = t + td(days=2 - t.weekday())
    tthu = t + td(days=3 - t.weekday())
    ffri = t + td(days=4 - t.weekday())
    ssat = t + td(days=5 - t.weekday())
    today = t.strftime('%#m-%#d-%Y')
    sun = ssun.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    mon = mmon.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    tue = ttue.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    wed = wwed.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    thu = tthu.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    fri = ffri.strftime('%#m-%#d')
    sat = ssat.strftime('%#m-%#d')

    return (today, sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat)

def admin_dashboard():
    (today, sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat) = get_dates()
    return today  

admin_dashboard()  #3-13-2018
```